# Find mouse world-coordinates (3D) on a quadtree heightmaped terrain

Tags: c++, directx, logic, terrain, quadtree

I'm trying to find the mouse position in world coordinates but am having trouble finding the right code. At the moment I use this to determine the ray:

```
float pointX, pointY;
D3DXMATRIX projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, inverseViewMatrix, worldMatrix, translateMatrix, inverseWorldMatrix;
D3DXVECTOR3 direction, origin, rayOrigin, rayDirection;
bool intersect, result;


// Move the mouse cursor coordinates into the -1 to +1 range.
pointX = ((2.0f * (float)mouseX) / (float)m_screenWidth) - 1.0f;
pointY = (((2.0f * (float)mouseY) / (float)m_screenHeight) - 1.0f) * -1.0f;

// Adjust the points using the projection matrix to account for the aspect ratio of the viewport.
m_Direct3D->GetProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
pointX = pointX / projectionMatrix._11;
pointY = pointY / projectionMatrix._22;

// Get the inverse of the view matrix.
m_Camera->GetViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
D3DXMatrixInverse(&inverseViewMatrix, NULL, &viewMatrix);

// Calculate the direction of the picking ray in view space.
direction.x = (pointX * inverseViewMatrix._11) + (pointY * inverseViewMatrix._21) + inverseViewMatrix._31;
direction.y = (pointX * inverseViewMatrix._12) + (pointY * inverseViewMatrix._22) + inverseViewMatrix._32;
direction.z = (pointX * inverseViewMatrix._13) + (pointY * inverseViewMatrix._23) + inverseViewMatrix._33;

// Get the origin of the picking ray which is the position of the camera.
origin = m_Camera->GetPosition();
```

This gives me the origin and direction of the ray.

But...

I use a custom mesh (not the one from directX) with a heightmap, separated into quadtrees and I don't know if my logic is correct, I tried using the frustum to determine which nodes in the quadtree are visible and so do the checking intersection of triangles only on those nodes, here is this code:

Note* m_mousepos is a vector.

```
bool QuadTreeClass::getTriangleRay(NodeType* node, FrustumClass* frustum, ID3D10Device* device, D3DXVECTOR3 vPickRayDir, D3DXVECTOR3 vPickRayOrig){


    bool result;
    int count, i, j, indexCount;
    unsigned int stride, offset;
    float fBary1, fBary2;
    float fDist;
    D3DXVECTOR3 v0, v1, v2;
    float p1, p2, p3;


    // Check to see if the node can be viewed.
    result = frustum->CheckCube(node->positionX, 0.0f, node->positionZ, (node->width / 2.0f));

    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }




    // If it can be seen then check all four child nodes to see if they can also be seen.
    count = 0;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(node->nodes[i] != 0)
        {
            count++;
            getTriangleRay(node->nodes[i], frustum, device, vPickRayOrig, vPickRayDir);
        }
    }

    // If there were any children nodes then dont continue

    if(count != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

        // Now intersect each triangle in this node

    j = 0;

    for(i=0; i<node->triangleCount; i++){

        j = i * 3;

        v0 = D3DXVECTOR3( node->vertexArray[j].x, node->vertexArray[j].y, node->vertexArray[j].z);
        j++;
        v1 = D3DXVECTOR3( node->vertexArray[j].x, node->vertexArray[j].y, node->vertexArray[j].z);
        j++;
        v2 = D3DXVECTOR3( node->vertexArray[j].x, node->vertexArray[j].y, node->vertexArray[j].z);

        result = IntersectTriangle( vPickRayOrig, vPickRayDir, v0, v1, v2, &fDist, &fBary1, &fBary2);

        if(result == true){

                        // intersection = true, so get a aproximate center of the triangle on the world

            p1 = (v0.x + v0.x + v0.x)/3;
            p2 = (v0.y + v1.y + v2.y)/3;
            p3 = (v0.z + v1.z + v2.z)/3;

            m_mousepos = D3DXVECTOR3(p1, p2, p3);

            return true;

        }

    }




}

bool QuadTreeClass::IntersectTriangle( const D3DXVECTOR3& orig, const D3DXVECTOR3& dir,D3DXVECTOR3& v0, D3DXVECTOR3& v1, D3DXVECTOR3& v2, FLOAT* t, FLOAT* u, FLOAT* v ){
    // Find vectors for two edges sharing vert0
    D3DXVECTOR3 edge1 = v1 - v0;
    D3DXVECTOR3 edge2 = v2 - v0;

    // Begin calculating determinant - also used to calculate U parameter
    D3DXVECTOR3 pvec;
    D3DXVec3Cross( &pvec, &dir, &edge2 );

    // If determinant is near zero, ray lies in plane of triangle
    FLOAT det = D3DXVec3Dot( &edge1, &pvec );

    D3DXVECTOR3 tvec;
    if( det > 0 )
    {
        tvec = orig - v0;
    }
    else
    {
        tvec = v0 - orig;
        det = -det;
    }

    if( det < 0.0001f )
        return FALSE;

    // Calculate U parameter and test bounds
    *u = D3DXVec3Dot( &tvec, &pvec );
    if( *u < 0.0f || *u > det )
        return FALSE;

    // Prepare to test V parameter
    D3DXVECTOR3 qvec;
    D3DXVec3Cross( &qvec, &tvec, &edge1 );

    // Calculate V parameter and test bounds
    *v = D3DXVec3Dot( &dir, &qvec );
    if( *v < 0.0f || *u + *v > det )
        return FALSE;

    // Calculate t, scale parameters, ray intersects triangle
    *t = D3DXVec3Dot( &edge2, &qvec );
    FLOAT fInvDet = 1.0f / det;
    *t *= fInvDet;
    *u *= fInvDet;
    *v *= fInvDet;


    return TRUE;
}
```

Please is this code right? If it is then my problem must be related to the quadtree.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by mouse position? AFAIK, mouse position is a 2D point on the screen.

Comment: The 3D coordinates of my mouse (intersecting it w/ my terrain)

Comment: that's not mouse position, that's intersection point of the mouse picking ray and the mesh, I think you should edit you question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over all visible triangle to find the intersection is very expensive. Additional the cost will rise if your heightmap gets finer.

For my heightmap I use a different approach:

I do a step-by-step search regarding the height on the clickray starting at the origin. At every step the current position is moved along the ray and tested against the height of the heightmap (therefore you need a heightfunction). If the current position is below the heightmap, the last intervall is searched again by an additional iteration to find a finer position. This works as long as your heightmap hasn't a too high frequency in the heightvalues regarding to the stepsize (otherwise you could jump over a peak).